# DYI Test Bench advice

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, case

My dad and I were having bit of a discussion on if running a test on motherboard (before actually put it inside a case) in the open will present a problem.

His concern is that he was worried that doing an open case test would not give motherboard enough grounding (via metal contact on screw/case) in additional to what PSU does.

I don't think it would present a problem because PSU has built in grounding.

An example rig would look similar to what is in picture below. Since wood doesn't have any static surface we avoid that problem.

[image: http://www.euclideanspace.com/tech/pc/pc2012/build/test/mb1_400.jpg]

Question: Is it better to put in case first for additional ground or is that unnecessary?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: I add in a question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it better to put in case first for additional ground or is that unnecessary?

It doesn't matter, most reviewers and a lot of hobbyists have test benches that vary in their degree of openness and material used. In your case, you have a completely open test bench made of wood. Nothing wrong with that.

Cases are for stability, protection, organization, noise reduction (kind of), and sometimes aesthetic. As long as the power supply is properly grounded there would be no risk to the hardware  that wouldn't exist if you assembled it in a case, aside from the case offering a bit of extra physical protection.